# Azure Worker Role Copy File from Linux VM

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-virtual-machine

I'm pretty new to the Azure Platform, I have tried to search on Google for any assistance but unfortunately my Google searching skills aren't the best.

I have a Linux VM in Azure, the Linux VM occasionally will have wav files on it, that will need to be copied off of it.

My plan is to use a Wokrer Role to access the Linux VM and copy the files off using scp, and then storing them in a storage account in Azure.

Is it possible to have a few pointers in the right direction of how this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, there would be no need for a worker role (which is nothing more than a Windows Server VM running in a Cloud Service). If you *did* need a worker role instance talking to a Linux instance, you'd have to connect them with a Virtual network. I'm guessing you're just starting out, and that solution sounds over-engineered.

Instead: Just write directly to blob storage from your linux-based app. If you're using .NET, Java, PHP, Python, or Ruby, there are already SDKs that handle this for you - go [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/?fb=en-us) and scroll down to Developer Centers, download the SDK of choice, and then look at some of the getting-started tutorials.

Just remember that blob storage is Storage-as-a-Service, accessible from anywhere. Underneath, it's just REST calls, with the language sdk's wrapping those calls.

There are more examples in the [Azure Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8396).

Comment: Thank you very much for this. With this route, is it possible to create a script to copy the files directly to the Storage. And then schedule the script to execute.